# php PDO no connection with database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I decided to create a sign-up web page and connect it with db, but I have a problem:

> **ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049]** Unknown database 'site' Fatal error:
>   Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sm\application\lib\PDOMain.class.php:20 Stack trace:
>   #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sm\application\lib\User.class.php(11): PDOMain->selectPDO('sign_up', '*', 'WHERE login='ad...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sm\home.php(4): User->getUserWhereLogin('admin') #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sm\application\lib\PDOMain.class.php
>   on line 20

I've been working on this for awhile, any help would be appreciated.

There I have PDOMain:

```
class PDOMain
{
    private $MPDO;

    function __construct($dbname = "site", $host ="localhost", $user ="root", $password ="")
    {
        try {
            $this->MPDO = new PDO ("mysql:dbname={$dbname};host={$host}", "{$user}", "{$password}");
            return $this->MPDO;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function selectPDO($db, $cols, $where = "", $order = "", $limit = "")
    {
        $sql = "SELECT{$cols} FROM `{$db}` {$where} {$order} {$limit}";
        $rs = $this->MPDO->query($sql);
        $rs->execute();
        if ($where != "") {
            $row = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $row;
        } else {
            $row = $rs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $row;
        }
    }
function insertPDO($db,$cols="",$values="")
{
if ($cols=="") echo "ERROR! </<br>";
$sql="INSERT INTO `{$db}`({$cols}) VALUES ({$values})";
$this->MPDO->query($sql);
}
function updatePDO($db,$what,$val,$where)
{
    $sql="UPDATE `{$db}` SET {$what}='{$val}' {$where}";
    $this->MPDO->query($sql);
}
function deletePDO($db,$where){
        $sql= "DELETE FROM `{$db}` {$where}";
        return $this->MPDO->query($sql);
}
}
```

There I have php class User:

```
require_once("PDOMain.class.php");
class User extends PDOMain{
    function __construct($table)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table=$table;
    }

    function getUserWhereLogin($login){
        $user=$this->selectPDO($this->table,"*","WHERE login='$login'");
        if(count($user)>0) return $user;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

And there I'm using it in home.php:

```
require_once("application/lib/User.class.php");
$userObject = new User("sign_up");
$user=$userObject->getUserWhereLogin("admin");
print_r($user);
```

[Here is a screenshot showing the schema of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW5TJ.png)

Comment: As per exception thrown, its clear that database does not exists named as **site**

Comment: do you have a database called "site"?

Comment: yes.I`m linked it after the code . Сould u look at that ?

Comment: The database **site** does not exist, is down, or your credentials are bad.